# MySql Packets Out of Order

Tags: php, mysql

Forgive me if this is a simple issue, I've been struggling for days with this.

I am migrating a client's WP site to MAMP in order to make some changes for her. I imported the DB to phpMyAdmin, and copied the site root to the folder that I have set up as the document root.

My Apache Port is 8888 and my PHP Port is 8889.

In my browser, I navigate to - `http://localhost:8889/`.

I keep getting this in the browser window:

> J���
>   5.5.33����}k~Z(VX7�ÿ÷�€����������HE`5%YpHW\J>�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got
>   packets out of order

Comment: That's your *MySQL connection port*, PHP "runs as part of" the web-server (Apache).

Answer (score 2):

that's a mysql service not a web-server, where you expecting phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2):

PHP do not uses any ports

Mysql use ports, and looks like 8889 in your case

To check web-site you need to `http://localhost:8888/`